# How to fix unresponsive UI (failing ajax calls) when session times out in apache wicket?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-security, wicket

I'm trying to fix unresponsive UI after session times out. Ajax requests fail because of HTTP 302 redirect to login page - ajax error is `Could not find root <ajax-response> element`.

I've subscribed to ajax failure event:

```
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/failure', function( attrs, jqXHR, textStatus, jqEvent, errorThrown ) {
    handleAjaxCallFailure(attrs, jqXHR, textStatus, jqEvent, errorThrown);
});
```

But I can't find any reasonable way to obtain http response, response code or other http headers. I've also tried:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    handleAjaxError(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError);
});
```

But this is not firing at all. I'm using apache wicket 7.6.0. Is there any other way to force user to login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some error on the line.

Usually Wicket will return a proper Ajax response (the XML) with a single element in `<redirect>../the/path/to/login</redirect>` and wicket-ajax-jquery.js will process it and make the redirect.

In addition there might be a response header named `Ajax-Location` which Wicket handles the same way.

Check the response headers and body. Paste them here too!

Comment: I believe that wicket won't even get the request because spring security filter will find out that session is invalid and that's why browser gets HTTP 302 with empty body and redirect location pointing to login page.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g , I've come up with custom implementation of LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint with custom redirect strategy for wicket ajax calls.